# JQuery file download with Ajax

Tags: jquery, file, download

I'm using John Culviner's great fileDownload plugin to produce a "please wait" message when my user chooses to generate a report.

When a user clicks a link, I send an ajax request to my PHP which generates a PDF on the server. At that point I am attempting to update the link in my success handler for the fileDownload plugin.

I may be approaching this wrong, but here's my code - any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$("body").on("click","##pdfLink", function(e){

    $.fileDownload($(this).attr('href'), {
        preparingMessageHtml: "Preparing your report, please wait...",
        failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."
    });

    // Build our data string.
    var strData = {method: "createPDF"};

    // Send a request to build our XL file.
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pdf.php',
        data: strData,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $("##pdfLink").attr("href","/pdf/"+data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
    return false; 
    e.preventDefault(); 
})
```

At this point, when I click the link the modal is displayed correctly with the "Please Wait" message. My file does get built on the server (Confirmed with my alert in my success handler), and my HREF does get updated. However, the plugin does not prompt the user for download.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a link for "John Culviner's great fileDownload plugin"?

Answer (score 2):

Probably , you need to start download ,after link's reference will be received:

```
 $("body").on("click","##pdfLink", function(e){
    // Build our data string.
    var strData = {method: "createPDF"};        

    var self = this;
    var $pdfGeneratingDialog = $('<div>',{
                   title:"Generating PDF",
                   text: "Please wait..."
                   }).dialog({modal:true});
    // Send a request to build our XL file.
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pdf.php',
        data: strData,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
           $pdfGeneratingDialog.dialog('close');

           alert(data);
           $(self).attr("href","/pdf/"+data);
           //starting download process
           $.fileDownload($(self).attr('href'), {
               preparingMessageHtml: "Preparing your report, please wait...",
               failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."
           });             
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This sort of defeats the purpose of the plugin, as it is supposed to give user some feedback while the file is generated. If I pop that message up upon success, the file will already be generated and the user won't see the message but for a second.

Comment: Unless your link's reference is not received, how should your 'downloader' know what to download??!!!! So you need to wait, untill server will respond. If you want to give feedback to user, then show your 'progress viewer' when ajax call starts.

Comment: Engineer, not sure I follow, do you mind posting an example of how I would display the message during the beginning of the call?

Answer (score 2):

You not need call ajax funcion in JS. Your link `<a href='yoursite.com/pdf.php'` identify with this command `$(this).attr('href')` location of you server process of pdf.

**EDIT:**

Your call:

```
// Build our data string.
var strData = {method: "createPDF"};

var $preparingFileModal = $("#preparing-file-modal");
$preparingFileModal.dialog({ modal: true });

$.fileDownload($(this).attr('href'), {
    httpMethod: "GET",
    data: strData
    successCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
        $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
        // In this case 
        $.fileDownload("/pdf/"+responseHtml, {
            preparingMessageHtml: "Download file",
            failMessageHtml: "Not work"
        });

    },
    failCallback: function (responseHtml, url) {
        $preparingFileModal.dialog('close');
        $("#error-modal").dialog({ modal: true });
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="preparing-file-modal" title="Preparing report..." style="display: none;">
    We are preparing your report, please wait...

    <div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-corner-left ui-corner-right" style="width: 100%; height:22px; margin-top: 20px;"></div>
</div>

<div id="error-modal" title="Error" style="display: none;">
    There was a problem generating your report, please try again.
</div>
```

Comment: I'm generating the pdf dynamically on the fly, passing params, hence the ajax call.

Comment: Passing parameters with this command `data: strData` in fileDownload calll

Comment: @JasonWells I change to make two call. One of `<a href="**URL**` to generate first,  and second call for download your data.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I will give this a shot but still not entirely sure I follow. If it works out, I will be back to make sure you are upvoted :) Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adjusting your timeout?

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/pdf.php',
        data: strData,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $("##pdfLink").attr("href","/pdf/"+data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
    return false; 
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: John: Yes I did, and there is an option in his plugin called checkInterval which I also upped to 5000, but no dice. My file takes about 2 seconds to generate.

Answer (score 0):

I also use jquery.filedownload for my app, I hope my solution would help someone else who has the similar requirement with me; and I change the usage just a little bit. i.e:

1. I use it with rails3
2. I want to display tweeter bootstrap modal instead of jquery's Dialog.

**A.** The client side (front-ent), below is the function that support for download file when user click on the file item on HTML page:

function DownloadFile(id, file_url, file_name, strTime){

```
$.fileDownload(file_url, {
    successCallback: function (url) {
        $("#ilulModaldow").find('#file_name').html(file_name);
        $("#ilulModaldow").find('#file_created_at').html(strTime);
        $("#ilulModaldow").modal();
        //DATNT comment: $("#ilulModaldow") is a normal tweeter modal
    },
    failCallback: function (html, url) {

        alert('Connection error! Please try again');
    }
});
```

}

**B.** server side (back-end), I created an action to send file, this action is the paramenter "file_url" of the javascript function above:

def download

```
a=APostAttach.find(params[:id])
send_file a.file.path(:original), :type => a.file_content_type
#DATNT comment: below is the way I set cookies for jquery.filedownload plugin requirement
cookies[:fileDownload] = true
cookies[:Path] = "/"
```

end

**C.** combine back-end and font-end based on item(file) click event:

```
$('#attach_<%= attach.id %>').click(function(){
    DownloadFile("<%= attach.id %>","<%= download_courses_path(:id => attach.id) %>","<%=attach.file_file_name %>","Uploaded at <%=  time_ago_in_words(attach.created_at).gsub('about','') + ' ago'%>");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following code to download a file in same window (without opening new tab). It works, although it doesn't have any error support...

```js
function downloadURL(url, callback) {

    var id = 'hiddenDownloader';
    $('body').append('<iframe id="' + id + '" style="display: block" src="' + url + '"></iframe>');

    var $iframe = $('#' + id);
    $iframe.on('load', function () {
        $iframe.remove();
        // no error support
        callback();
    });
}


downloadURL('http://example.com', function() {
  alert('Done');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```